# SAP GUI on other device 'The control could not be found by id.'

Tags: python, scripting, sap-gui

I am using anaconda python 3 and SAP GUI 770.
I am trying to create an SAP GUI automate program and create an application on other devices.

When the program arrive export spreadsheet method it stops working with this error:

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (619, 'SAP Frontend Server', 'The control could not be found by id.', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapfront.HLP', 393215, 0), None)

and when saving the file I have material Document list dialog window and the other device has windows dialog window

[image: material Document List dialog]

Code:

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = folderdir
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = filename
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 3
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
```

Comment: Please indicate the **steps to reproduce** the two cases: the one for which you obtain the "Material Document List" popup, the one for which you obtain the "Windows dialog window". I don't get how it's possible in the exact same context to obtain two different results.

Comment: Note that you should look at the SAP GUI option "Show native Microsoft Windows dialogs" on each SAP GUI installation using your script.

Comment: yes it's unmarked and when I start recording the script I got Material Document List popup.I created executable exe file and put it other device the program failed that error because got a windows dialog but "Show native Microsoft Windows dialogs" is unmarked. Do you have any idea why this happen?

Comment: For both devices, if it's exactly the same SAP GUI version, same SAP backend application accessed, same connection parameters, same automation, then it must be a bug and you should test with the latest SAP GUI version/patch. In the end, you may contact the SAP Support.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just paste this line and it's all good now.
I hope to help somebody with this.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[1]/menu[1]").select()
session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press()
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = folderdir
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = filename
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 3
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
```